# How many times a timespan occurs between two Datetimes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime

----EDIT----

Oh im sorry that was a huge misstake :)

Let me ask the question again...

Heres an example,

```
Datetime startTime = 2011-10-08 12:30:00
Datetime endTime = 2011-10-10 15:00:00
```

How many times does 12:00:00 - 13:00:00 occur between the two datetimes?

```
2011-10-08 12:30:00 - 2011-10-08 13:00:00 Not Ok (time has alredy started)
2011-10-09 12:00:00 - 2011-10-09 13:00:00 Ok
2011-10-10 12:00:00 - 2011-10-10 13:00:00 Ok
```

Expecting result 2.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you expect it to be three?  A TimeSpan represents a length of time.  Your example represents 13 hours, 0 minutes and 0 seconds.  Could you please provide more detail about what you want to accomplish?

Comment: Are you trying to determine how many 13 hour periods occur in the time between your start and end times OR are you trying to determine how many time 13:00 (1pm) occurs between the given start/end times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing your update you will want to do something like determine the days to check and do a bounds check to see if the times specific fall within your start and end dates. As an idea, here is some sample code I threw together.

```
    private static void CheckTimes()
    {
        DateTime start = DateTime.Parse("2011-10-08 12:30:00");
        DateTime end = DateTime.Parse("2011-10-10 15:00:00");
        // variable to use for bound checking (Date property sets the hour to 00)
        DateTime boundscheck = start.Date;
        // variable containing results
        int timesFound = 0;

        // This loop assumes we are only looking for one match per day
        for (int i = 0; i <= (end - start).Days; i++)
        {
            // set the lower bound to yyyy-mm-dd 12:00:00
            var lowerbound = boundscheck.Date.AddHours(12);
            // set the upper bound to yyyy-mm-dd 13:00:00
            var upperbound = lowerbound.AddHours(1);
            //determine if bounds are within our start and end date
            if (lowerbound >= start && upperbound <= end)
            {
                timesFound++;
            }
            // increment boundscheck variable by one day
            boundscheck = boundscheck.AddDays(1);
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks alot! Just what I was looking for! Great job!

Answer (score 4):

```
(endTime-startTime).Ticks/timeSpan.Ticks
```

Answer (score 1):

Take the difference of the two days, divided by the interval.

```
TimeSpan timeSpan = new TimeSpan(24, 00, 00); // one day

DateTime start = new DateTime(2011, 10, 08, 11, 00, 00);
DateTime end = new DateTime(2011, 10, 10, 23, 00, 00); // 2 and 1/2 days later

var occurances = ((end - start).Ticks / (float)timeSpan.Ticks); // 2.5f
```